# Data format issue for related models (Laravel / jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

Tags: laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

Here is an [open bug on Github](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/1426) for the laravel-mongodb package, but there is no response. Maybe someone knows a solution..?

When selecting as single doc, dates displays as a date

```
{
    "_id": "5ca71ce0d542352064004034",
    "title": "General review",
    "status": "active",
    "start_date": "2019-04-05 09:16:16.000000",
    "end_date": "2038-01-19 03:14:07.000000",
    "start_review_date": "2019-04-05 09:16:16.000000",
    "submission_fee": 100,
    "reward": 0,
    "is_general_review_round": true,
    "created_at": "2019-04-05 09:16:16.000000",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-05 09:16:16.000000",
    "proposals": [],
    "demography": null
}
```

But on select as related object (nested array) I have this date conversion issue...

```
{
    "title": "Omnis perspiciatis aut voluptatem dolores vel repudiandae.",
    "start_date": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1554542206000"
        }
    },
    "end_date": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1556183806000"
        }
    },
    "start_review_date": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1555406206000"
        }
    },
    "updated_at": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1554455806312"
        }
    },
    "created_at": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1554455806312"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dates can be formatted from parent model:
If your parent model is User and you are embedding UserDetails you could cast dates this way:

```
public function userDetails()
{
    return $this->embedsOne('UserDetails');
}
```

`protected $dates = ['userDetails.created_at', 'userDetails.updated_at'];`

Comment: this seems to be the right answer. The $dates array defines which elements should be considered of type MongoDate and transformed to Iso when read from DB